# Exporting 3 gridviews to excel into 3 different worksheets

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, excel

From my website, I have a button which calls a method and then generates reports to excel. the code works. The problem is that the code displays all gridviews (there are 3) on the same tab. What code may I add to this so that when i click on the button, it will download the document but have each gridview displayed on their separate tabs. The tab names will be top 1, top 2, and top 3. So to clarify, right now all of the gridviews are displayed on the top 1 tab, I need to make 2 more tabs (top 2 and top 3) and put gridview2 on top 2 tab, and gridview3 on the top 3 tab.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;



public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ISALog1ConnectionString"].ToString());

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("exec ProxyReport", conn);
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 200;

    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ad.Fill(dataSet);

    GridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView2.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[1];
    GridView2.DataBind();
    GridView3.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[2];
    GridView3.DataBind();

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=Top 1.xls";
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
    GridView2.RenderControl(htw);
    GridView3.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{

}


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to add EPPlus from codeplex: http://epplus.codeplex.com/  and then add this to your code. You can use it to add as many worksheets as you want:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.IO;
    using OfficeOpenXml;
    using System.Configuration;

    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetExcel ge = new GetExcel();
    ge.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
}

public class GetExcel : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ISALog1ConnectionString"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("exec ProxyReport", conn);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 200;
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ad.Fill(dataSet);

       GridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
       GridView1.DataBind();
       GridView2.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[1];
       GridView2.DataBind();
       GridView3.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[2];
       GridView3.DataBind();   

        dataSet.Tables[0].TableName = "1";
        dataSet.Tables[1].TableName = "2";
        dataSet.Tables[2].TableName = "3";

        int count = 3;   

            MemoryStream ms = GetExcel.DataTableToExcelXlsx(dataSet, count);
            ms.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=EPPlusData.xlsx");
            context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            context.Response.End();

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static MemoryStream DataTableToExcelXlsx(DataSet ds, int count)
    {
        MemoryStream Result = new MemoryStream();
        ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage();

        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            DataTable table = ds.Tables[i.ToString()];
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("MySheet" + i.ToString());

            int col = 1;
            int row = 1;

            foreach (DataColumn cl in table.Columns)
            {
                ws.Cells[row, col].Value = cl.ColumnName;
                col++;
            }
            col = 1;
            foreach (DataRow rw in table.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn cl in table.Columns)
                {
                    if (rw[cl.ColumnName] != DBNull.Value)
                        ws.Cells[row + 1, col].Value = rw[cl.ColumnName].ToString();
                    col++;
                }
                row++;
                col = 1;
            }
        }
        pack.SaveAs(Result);
        return Result;
    }
}}
```

Comment: Where do I put the files into from EPPlus?

Comment: I would recommend you put them in the bin folder of your app. Then you just have to add a reference to the dll and you are done.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to add a reference, can you guide me through on how to do that?

Comment: Okay, I went to the website tab in visual studios, then clicked add reference... and opened up the dll file. Then I copied and pasted the code into mine, and it gave me 4 errors where excelpackage, excelworkbook is. Did I not reference it correctly? error said the namespace could not be found for 3 of the errors. and the last one says dbserver does not exist in the current context

Comment: I apologize, DBServer does not apply in your case. Take a look at the sample application so that you can see how it is done. Click on "EPPlus 2.7.0.1 Sample Including Binary": http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/47316

Comment: You need to read in your datatable where you see "DBServer" in the code. Can you access your datasource here and bypass your gridview?

Comment: +1 for the link to epplus. Do you know if NPOI allows the same multisheet output, since epplus will not save to xls format?

Comment: I don't think i can bypass that. I looked over the sample but i'm still confused about what I need to do :(

Comment: Okay, tell me how you are getting data to your gridview and I will tell you how to get it programmatically to the datatable that is being exported. Is the data coming from a sql server database?

Comment: yes i am getting it from sql server 2008. i have it in a stored procedure.

Comment: EDIT - I just changed the sample code so that it retrieves data from stored procedures. Of course, you are going to have to update the code for your server name, database name and 3 stored procedures names. This works, I just tested it.

Comment: Thank you, you have been very helpful. There are a few points I would like to make. I only have 1 stored procedure. The name is "ProxyReport" or dbo.ProxyReport but in my code above it says "exec ProxyReport" which one shall i put into the name? I also don't know what to do with the other 2 stored procedures because I only have 1 which generates a loop to get 3 tables. Also.. when i open up sql server.. it says server name: ihs-wwdcc1 would that be what i put into the YOUR_SERVER part? and YOUR_DATABASE in my code above it says "ISALog1ConnectionString" but the database in my sqlserver

Comment: Okay, I just updated the code so that it has your connection string and your gridviews. Really, you should just be able to copy and paste this and it should work.

Comment: Sorry I was out for the weekend. I ran your code and it threw me 6 errors that says cannot access a non-static of outer type '_Default' via nested type '_Default.GetExcel' it starts on the line GridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0]; and the 5 below it. Thanks for you're help, I appreciate it.